# Nuance for 沼沢、泥沼、沼地、沼、沼田

Tags: synonyms

What is the main difference between these 5 vocab words? I understand they all equate to something like a marsh or swamp, but do they hold any specific differences like marsh/swamp/bog do in English? (Admittedly I had to look up the differences, but they do exist.)
I know [沼田]{ぬまた} refers to a rice field of some kind, but how does it differ from any other rice field?

Answer (score 3):

Japanese is unparticular about those wetland terrains. Some words actually have formal definitions, only they are contradicting each other across fields on translations like [this](https://jglobal.jst.go.jp/detail?JGLOBAL_ID=200906068946379794), proven to be not very useful either.

- **沼【ぬま】**

  The most basic word referring to *marsh* or *swamp* (I guess they are most general terms in English). [The dictionary](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/169397/meaning/m0u/%E6%B2%BC/) says "water shallower than *lake* (湖) whose depth is under 5 meter". The word is so strongly associated with the image of *muddy pool*, that where clear water is seen, such as [Oze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozegahara), are usually called 湿地 "wetland" or 湿原 "moor(?)" instead of 沼.

  In the figurative language, 沼 often carries the similar connotation to those of English *swamp, morass,* or *mire*, that means "inescapable difficult situation". It particularly has a sense as internet slang to mean "addiction" or "easily addictive subject". FWIW I've heard of オーディオ沼 or レンズ沼.

  > 沼にはまる *get stuck in the swamp*
- **沼地【ぬまち】**

  沼 and 沼地 is just like *swamp* and *swamp**land***. 沼 itself refers to the "pool" (where the ground is under water) but 沼地 the terrain generally consists of 沼 but maybe not entirely.
- **泥沼【どろぬま】**

  The word is mostly figurative than indicating the actual *bog* (泥炭地). Compared with 沼, which suggests personal predicament caused by a vicious cycle, it is rather likely to depict the situation many factors entangled to make everyone stagnant, such as the quagmire of the Vietnam war.
- **沼沢【しょうたく】**

  This is a mostly academic blanket term generally referring to shallow wetland. [The dictionary definition](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/109298/meaning/m0u/) is "water shallower than 沼 whose depth is under 1 meter". Also read ぬまざわ or ぬまさわ for proper names.
- **沼田【ぬまた】**

  Literally should be "swamp patty" or something but I don't really think it's used outside proper names.